# Generate variables with while loop for variable names

Tags: loops, stata

I am trying to do the operation below:

```
local i=2
while `i'<10 {
gen diff0`i' = f1ysveny0`i'-sveny0`i-1'
local i=`i'+1
}
```

However, this seems not to be working:

```
`i'-1
```

How should I code the sentence in order to do with a `while` loop something like the following:

```
gen diff08=f1ysveny08-sveny07
gen diff09=f1ysveny09-sveny08
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `while`. Use `forvalues` instead:

```
forvalues i = 2/9 { 
    generate diff0`i' = f1ysveny0`i' - sveny0`=`i'-1'
}
```

Your error lies in thinking that

```
`i-1'
```

is equivalent to

```
`=`i'-1'
```

but it isn't. In your code Stata just sees as a macro reference `i-1` but minus signs can't be part of Stata names. Certainly the whole is not an expression as you need the second syntax: first, to refer to local macro `i`; then to subtract 1; and finally to get Stata to use the result of the expression.

Your code error was not fatal in itself, as macro references that don't make sense get evaluated as empty strings. But (I guess) you ended up referring to a variable name not in your dataset, as `sveny0` isn't mentioned in your code.

Beginners often find this easier:

```
forvalues i = 2/9 { 
    local j = `i' - 1 
    generate diff0`i' = f1ysveny0`i' - sveny0`j'
}
```